# Can Fiddler capture Service Fabric Traffic?

Tags: http, azure-service-fabric, fiddler

How can you capture http traffic from services on Local Service Fabric Cluster with Fiddler?
I have a Service Fabric Cluster set up on my local machine, and I need to capture the traffic that goes from these services to external providers.  I'm using Swagger to kick off the requests, but I am finding that whilst Fiddler is recording the communications from my browser to the services, it's not recording the communications from these services to external providers.

I've read up on it a little bit, and haven't really progressed any further, as most of the discussions seem to centre around services and IIS, rather than Service Fabric specifically.

Having said that, I've still tried suggestions such as the ones contained [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-no-longer-capturing-web-service-requests-in-net) , but with no joy.

I'm assuming that I somehow need to route Service Fabric through the Fiddler Proxy(I've previously had to do this with Gatling load testing in order for it to show on Fiddler), but I've no idea how to do that or if it's even possible?!?

Comment: What exactly is the end goal you are looking to achieve?

Comment: I was just hoping to see the http request that was being sent to an external service, and ensure that it contained the data I was expecting it to contain.

Comment: I am sure you can capture the traffic but as you mentioned you might need to do some additional configuration. Have you tried something other than fiddler to capture traffic? Maybe wire shark